# What is the meaning of this regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to figure out what this regular expression means?

```
"^[A-Z]{3}-[4-7]\d{2,4}\$$"
```

I think it starts with exactly 3 letters and ends with 2,3 or 4 digits (also not sure about the dubble $-sings) .

But I can't understand what this means:

```
     -[4-7]
```

And I'm also not sure why there are 2 $ at the end ...

thanks

Comment: This is basic regex syntax. Check out: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `^` the start of the string
- `[A-Z]{3}` a character from A to Z repeated 3 times
- `-` the character `-`
- `[4-7]` a digit from 4 to 7
- `\d{2,4}` any digit from 0 to 9 repeated between 2 and 4 times
- `\$` the character `$`
- `$` the end of the string

Comment: ^ = start of the string, $ end of the string, [4-7] a digit

Comment: @ridgerunner So if there was a newline in the string, **and** the `m` flag was set, it would look twice - once per each half, and try to match the regex each time? I've never had to use the `m` flag before, but that's how I just decided to interpret it. Is that right?

Comment: @Ian - The `$` is a zero width assertion, or _anchor_, that matches a _position_ - it does not match any character at all. Normally it only matches the position after the last character in the string. When the `m` _multiline_ flag is set, it also matches at the position before each and every newline `\n` (or possibly before a line termination sequence `\r\n` on Windows systems? Not sure about that detail.) Try it and see!

Comment: @ridgerunner thank you man! I see now:
- i thout -[4-7] was 1 expression, but it is seperate
- the \$ needs a backslash because it's a 'special' character in regexpr

Cheers !!

Answer (score 4):

### [Regular Expressions 101](http://www.regex101.com/r/tX3wZ9)

Go to [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com/) and paste the regex in there...it will describe it to you.  This will allow you to also test your regex within your browser.

*give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime*

**REGEX**

```
/"^[A-Z]{3}-[4-7]\d{2,4}\$$"/
```

***Description***

```
" Literal "
^ Start of string
Char class [A-Z] 3 times [greedy] matches:
    A-Z A character range between Literal A and Literal Z
    - Literal -
Char class [4-7]  matches:
    4-7 A character range between Literal 4 and Literal 7
\d 2 to 4 times [greedy] Digit [0-9]
\$ Literal $
$ End of string
" Literal "
```

***Visualization*** (thanks to [naomik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633183/naomik)) provided by [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 2):

Visualize!

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Also, that's not a Regular Expression (RegExp); that's just a string.

If you want to make it a RegExp:

```
var re = new RegExp("^[A-Z]{3}-[4-7]\\d{2,4}\\$$");
```

Or just

```
var re = /^[A-Z]{3}-[4-7]\d{2,4}\$$/;
```

Comment: Where is that visualization from?! I've seen that on SO before (or something like it) and was looking for the site the other day!

Answer (score 0):

`-[4-7]` means the character `-` followed by one of the characters `4`, `5`, `6` and `7`.

The first `$` is escaped - so it indicates a `$` in the input, whereas the second `$` is not escaped, and so it indicates the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

`-`: this is literally the minus `-` character.

`[4-7]`: a single digit, either 4,5,6 or 7.

`\$` is just an escaped `$` sign, so it's interpreted as text, and not as "end of string".